# 'hadoop' command silently failing upon execution

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to set up Hadoop for the first time on my local machine (masOS) in Pseudodistributed Mode.

I had previously installed Hadoop via Homebrew and then proceeded to update the configuration files in `$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/etc/hadoop` directory such as `core-site.xml` etc following instructions found in *Appendix A: Installing Apache Hadoop chapter of Hadoop the Definitive Guidebook (4th edition)*

However, I am now at a stage where when I run `hadoop version` I get nothing. The exit code for the previous command is `0` and nothing is sent to `stdout`. Starting a new shell produces the same behaviour..

```
13:35:33 ✔ ~  :: hadoop version
13:35:37 ✔ ~  ::
13:36:05 ✔ ~  :: hadoop version
13:36:11 ✔ ~  :: echo $?
0
```

Below is a snippet from my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Hadoop home directory configuration
HADOOP_VERSION_BREW=$(brew list --versions hadoop | awk '{print $2}')
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/$HADOOP_VERSION_BREW
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar

export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I'm quite confused here, but as a Hadoop newbie I wonder if there is something subtle that I am missing.

N.B. `which hadoop` gives: `/usr/local/bin/hadoop` which is symlinked to the Homebrew location:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 tallamjr admin   33 Oct 22 10:00  hadoop -> ../Cellar/hadoop/3.2.1/bin/hadoop
```

Comment: I would suggest not using Homebrew's Hadoop. I've had issues with it on my Mac